# how to transform a df by combing 2 fields

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe, and I would like to transform it to another df with all unique combination of 2 fields.

now i can achieve with some bulky for loops but guess there should be pandas native way to achive it?

thanks

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'],
                   'B' : ['B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
                   'C' : ['C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','J'],
                   'D' : ['D','E','F','G','H','I','J','J','J'],
                   'E' : ['E','F','G','H','I','J','A','B','C'],
                   'F' : ['B','C','D','B','C','D','B','C','D'],
                  })
list = ['A','B','C','D']
for a in df.A.unique():
    for b in list:
        res = df[(df.A==a) & (df.B==b)]
        if (len(res)>0):
            fi = res.iloc[0]
            print('{}:{},{},{},{},{},{},{}'.format(a,b,fi.C,fi.D,fi.E,fi.F,'found',str(len(res))))
        else:
            print('{}:{},,,,,{},{}'.format(a,b,'empty',str(len(res))))
```

expected results but in df

```
A:A,,,,,empty,0
A:B,C,D,E,B,found,1
A:C,,,,,empty,0
A:D,,,,,empty,0
B:A,,,,,empty,0
B:B,,,,,empty,0
B:C,D,E,F,C,found,1
B:D,,,,,empty,0
C:A,,,,,empty,0
C:B,,,,,empty,0
C:C,,,,,empty,0
C:D,E,F,G,D,found,1
D:A,,,,,empty,0
D:B,,,,,empty,0
D:C,,,,,empty,0
D:D,,,,,empty,0
E:A,,,,,empty,0
E:B,,,,,empty,0
E:C,,,,,empty,0
E:D,,,,,empty,0
F:A,,,,,empty,0
F:B,,,,,empty,0
F:C,,,,,empty,0
F:D,,,,,empty,0
G:A,,,,,empty,0
G:B,,,,,empty,0
G:C,,,,,empty,0
G:D,,,,,empty,0
H:A,,,,,empty,0
H:B,,,,,empty,0
H:C,,,,,empty,0
H:D,,,,,empty,0
I:A,,,,,empty,0
I:B,,,,,empty,0
I:C,,,,,empty,0
I:D,,,,,empty,0
```

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of the expected DataFrame? Not sure what "expected results but in df" would translate to...

Comment: i think the logic is like below tho i am not sure how to present well in pandas. thanks

expected_df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B']: all combination of [for all in df.A.unique()],[for all in list],
                           ['C','D','E','F']: {with the above AB combination, C|D|E|F value of the first entry},
                           'found': if (len(df[(df.A==a) & (df.B==b)])>0): return 'found'; else: return 'empty
                           'count': len(df[(df.A==a) & (df.B==b)])